# Error in Grails/GORM: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Looks like this has been asked many many times before, and I have looked into several of those, including the "[GORM Gotchas (Part 2)](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/)" by Peter Ledbrook, but still cannot seem to figure it out in my case. I have a `user` which has many `projects`, and a `project` belongs to a `user`. Then there is a `skill` which has many `projects` associated with it, but a `project` does NOT belong to a `skill`. When I try to remove a `project` from a `user`, I get that error. The domain classes are as follows:

```
    package grailstuts

    class User {
        String name

        static constraints = { name(nullable: true) }

        static mapping = { projects cascade: "all-delete-orphan" }

        static hasMany = [ projects: Project ]
    }
```

```
    package grailstuts

    class Project {
        String title

        static constraints = { title(nullable: true) }

        static belongsTo = [ user: User ]
    }
```

```
    package grailstuts

    class Skill {
        String name

        static constraints = { name(nullable: true) }

        static mapping = { projects cascade: "all-delete-orphan" }

        static hasMany = [ projects: Project ]
    }
```

When I run the integration test as follows, the part containing `foundUser.removeFromProjects(foundProject1)` seems to have the issue.

```
    package grailstuts

    import spock.lang.*

    class SkillIntegrationSpec extends Specification {
        void "adding and deleting projects"() {
            given: "A user, and projects added to the user"
            def user = new User().save(failOnError: true)
            def project1 = new Project(title: "java, groovy")
            def project2 = new Project(title: "java, scala")
            user.addToProjects(project1)
            user.addToProjects(project2)

            when: "Projects are also added to skill entry"
            def java = new Skill(name: 'java').save(failOnError: true)
            java.addToProjects(project1)
            java.addToProjects(project2)
            def groovy = new Skill(name: 'groovy').save(failOnError: true)
            groovy.addToProjects(project1)
            def scala = new Skill(name: 'scala').save(failOnError: true)
            scala.addToProjects(project2)

            then: "Each skill entry has its corresponding projects"
            Skill.findByName("java").projects.size() == 2
            Skill.findByName("groovy").projects.size() == 1
            Skill.findByName("scala").projects.size() == 1

            when: "Some projects are deleted from the database"
            def foundUser = User.get(user.id)
            def foundProject1 = Project.findByTitle("java, groovy")
            foundUser.removeFromProjects(foundProject1)

            then: "The deleted projects are also reflected in the skill entry"
            Skill.findByName("java").projects.size() == 1
            Skill.findByName("groovy").projects.size() == 0
            Skill.findByName("scala").projects.size() == 1
        }
    }
```

The first `given:... when:... then:...` block in the above test verifies fine. In the second `when:...` block when I try to remove the `project` from the `user`, that is when the error seem to occur. The error looks something like this ...

```
    | Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
    | Failure:  adding and deleting projects(grailstuts.SkillIntegrationSpec)
    |  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [grailstuts.Project#2]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [grailstuts.Project#2]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing_closure2(GormStaticApi.groovy:102)
        at grailstuts.SkillIntegrationSpec.adding and deleting projects(SkillIntegrationSpec.groovy:34)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [grailstuts.Project#2]
        ... 2 more
    | Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
    | Tests FAILED  - view reports in C:\Grails\grailstuts\target\test-reports
```

I am using:

```
    Grails version: 2.3.1
    Groovy version: 2.1.8
    JVM version: 1.7.0_45
```

Have spent quite a bit of time digging for some solution, but no luck yet. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`all-delete-orphan` - Applies only to one-to-many associations and 
indicates that 
**when a child is removed from an association then it  should be automatically deleted**
. Children are also deleted when the 
parent is. So when you call `foundUser.removeFromProjects(foundProject1)` you are trying to delete `foundProject1` object but it cannot be deleted from DB becouse `Skill` entity still have reference this project. How to fix it:

- First approach: Remove `projects cascade: "all-delete-orphan"` from `User` to prevent deleting projects when you call `user.removeFromProjects(...)`
- Second approach: Call `skill.removeFromProjects(...)` with the save project so the project will be deleted

Comment: Thank you @araxn1d, your explanation was simple, understandable, and simply elegant -- it worked in the first try. Both the approaches worked just fine. In my case when I delete a `project`, I also want it to be deleted from the DB, so the second approach applies. But thank you for explaining it both ways, it provides a complete picture, and it is much clearer how the whole thing works in this case. From your explanation, it also seemed like I did NOT need the `static mapping = { projects cascade: "all-delete-orphan" }` in the `Skill` class, and sure enough I did not need that! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that i've helped you. Good luck with your grails app development =)

Comment: Thanks, @araxn1d. Looks like in my many attempts before, I had tried something similar to the 2nd approach. However, it was not working because I was trying to delete multiple projects, and I was trying to remove all the projects from their respective users FIRST, and THEN trying to remove the projects from associations, and that was not working. When I do the other way, meaning FIRST remove from associations, and only THEN remove from parents, it works. So the order seems to matter, and it makes sense now. Thanks a ton for the clear and concise explanation!